# Pipeline artifacts REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Since Microsoft recommends using [pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts) instead of [build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts), I am looking for the REST API documentation. The [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) does not seem to have anything on pipeline artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

> The current documentation does not seem to have anything on pipeline
>   artifacts.

Don't worry, this doc you concerned both work to `Build Artifacts` and `Pipeline Artifacts`. You can continue reference to this doc to do operations on `pipeline artifacts`.

[image]

You can see that this api can get both Build artifacts and Pipeline artifacts info.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my original question. I need REST API for managing new pipeline artifacts. See DedupStoreHttpClient in https://www.myget.org/feed/nugetvssprivate/package/nuget/vss-api-netcore.

Comment: @AlexI, Could you express more on the exactly action you want to do? Sorry, little confused on what you are looking for.

Comment: my understanding is that the new API I am talking about can do mini match filtering on the server. From what I can tell, the URL looks similar to this:

`https://vsblobprodeus21.vsblob.visualstudio.com/<some_guid>/_apis/dedup/chunks/<some_encoded_value>`